# How to understand this negative index array variable declaration?

Tags: fortran

I am trying to understand (and reproduce) the following array declaration in a fortran code segment I am editing

```
real, dimension (-posint:) :: test_array
```

Here, `posint` is a positive integer. I am confused about how the negative indexing syntax works, as I have attempted to reproduce with a MWE, but it failed to compile:

```
program Array_Games

    implicit none

    integer, dimension(-3:,3) :: test_array

    test_array = reshape((/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 /), shape(test_array))

end program Array_Games
```

The compilation error is: `Error: Bad array specification for assumed shape array at (1)`.

However, changing the array index declaration slightly in `test_array`  compiles successfully:

```
program Array_Games

    implicit none

    integer, dimension(-3:-1,3) :: test_array

    test_array = reshape((/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 /), shape(test_array))

end program Array_Games
```

Therefore, the question is: how does the array declaration, here,

```
real, dimension (-posint:) :: test_array
```

work (i.e. compile without error)? I would have expected it to look more like

```
real, dimension (-posint:another_number) :: test_array
```

where `another_number` is another integer.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by __how does the array declaration, here, work?__  If you're getting an error message, then the compiler appears to be working.  The definition of an `explicit-array-spec` is `[lower-bound :] upper-bound`, which your code does not match.

Comment: Clarified in question. Declarations of the sort ``real, dimension (-posint:) :: test_array`` are used 1000s of time in the code. This is a well-benchmarked code that has been running for ~ 20 years, so I know it works! I just don't understand these variable declarations.

Comment: It would be helpful to know, which line the error message flags.   Do you know the difference between `explicit-array-spec` and `assumed-shaped-spec`?  `test_array` is not a dummy argument, so it cannot be an assumed-shaped array.  So, you're dealing with an explicit-shape array.  You need to specify an upper bound.

Comment: The fact that ``test_array`` is actually a dummy variable might be the issue: it's a dummy variable (with intent (in)) in a subroutine. I omitted this detail b/c I thought it was irrelevant, plus I wrote my own code snippet with a subroutine and an unspecified upper index, and it still failed to compile. I do not know the difference between ``explicit-array-spec`` and ``assumed-shaped-spec``, but will investigate; I'm guessing that ``assumed-shaped-spec`` can have an unspecified upper bound? If so, I will try to write my own MWE again.

Comment: What compiler are you using, including version number? Exactly which flags are you compiling with? Have you tried adding the appropriate flags to enforcer standards compliance?

Comment: @jack Yes, that perfectly answers my question. Thank you.

Comment: @IanBush Compiling with gcc version 10.2.0 (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0) for the toy code I wrote above. I am not compiling with any flags, compile command is simply: gfortran Array_Games.f90. Which flags do you recommend I add?

Comment: -Wall -Wextra -std=f2008 for starters